# MediaPlayer and error when playing music from online

Tags: android, server

```
        mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("192.168.191.1/test.mp3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

above is my code. It works well from such url: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3
But it don't work when I try to access mp3 file in my server, 192.168.191.1/test.mp3, and I use wamp for my server.

Comment: Are you running your app in your real device?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and it is working on my end :

```
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource("mp3 link"
            );
    player.prepare();
                player.start();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have find the solution, change

Comment: change setDataSource("192.168.191.1/test.mp3) to setDataSource(context,Uri.parse("http://192.168.191.1/test.mp3) work fine for me.